# Android AsycTask elapsed time calculation

Tags: java, android, date, android-asynctask

I'm trying to calculate the time elapsed in the execution of an AsyncTask, but nothing is logged in onPostExecute method, What I'm doing wrong?

Here is a part of my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        this.dialog.setMessage(mensagem);
        this.dialog.show();
        Date date = new Date();
        startTime = date.getTime();
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {

        if(this.dialog.isShowing() && this.dialog != null)
            this.dialog.dismiss();

        Date date = new Date();
        endTime = date.getTime();

        long diffTime = endTime - startTime;
//here nothing is logged in LogCat
        Log.d("TEMPO DE REQUISIÇÃO", String.valueOf(diffTime) + " milisegundos");
```

Comment: Did you set your log output level to debug?

Comment: I have used the log in the entire application with no problems, just in this especific case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve the problem just going to project -> clean and now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

```
long startTime, endTime; //declare this globally

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
     startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     ...
     ...
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
    endTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(endTime-startTime); //Milli Secs
    System.out.println((endTime-startTime)/1000); //Secs
     ...
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check LogCat level, is at `Debug`.
2. Make sure you are not cancelling the `AsyncTask` while it is running otherwise `onPostExecute` won't run.
3. Also if this is being run in a `Service` there maybe issues with the `Looper` not being set if the `AsyncTask` is not running.
4. Try changing "TEMPO DE REQUISIÇÃO" to "TEMPO DE REQUISICAO" as it might be that LogCat does not support the character encoding.

Comment: 1. I have used the log in the entire application with no problems, just in this especific case

Comment: 2. The AsyncTask is not being canceled, I have more code after the sample the is executed.

Comment: @DaniloSilva Try number 4

Comment: The encoding is not the problem, after test changing the encondinG, with no success, I just go to project -> clean, and now it is working showing me TEMPO DE EXECUÇÃO.